# Creating JSON data using PHP and parsing it using jQuery

Tags: php, ajax, json

I am using a PHP script to create JSON data. It looks like this:

```
{"Id":0}
```

Now if I put that into a file and then load it using ajax it's fine. But if I request this from the PHP script I get

> parsererror | SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Here is the code that I am using to load the JSON from the PHP:

```
$.ajax({
                    url: 'check.php',
                    data: {
                        username: 'LOL',
                        password: '1234'
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#result').html('#Id=' + data.Id);
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        $('#result').html(textStatus + ' | ' + errorThrown);
                    }
                });
```

Here is the PHP code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<?php

    echo '{"Id":0}';

?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you requesting it from PHP?

Comment: @Pradeep: Edit done
@ultimatebuster: Yes I know thank you

Comment: PHP error messages usually state the file and line the error occurred

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doctypes belong on HTML documents, not JSON.

Try something like this in your PHP file (and only this)

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
?>
{"Id":0}
```

Given what you have posted, I can't see any reason to even involve PHP. I'm guessing you've only posted a very simple example. Should it become more complex, involving server-side processing, data retrieval, etc, use PHP's `json_encode()`, for example

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$data = array(
    'Id'  => 0,
    'foo' => $someOtherComplexVariable
);
echo json_encode($data);
exit;
```

Comment: @Joaquín was adding an example as you commented :)

Answer (score 1):

In your error function use this and check what data is being returned from the server.

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   $('#result').html(textStatus + ' | ' + errorThrown + ' | ' + jqXHR.responseText);
   alert(jqXHR.responseText);
}
```

You will know where exactly it is going wrong. The data type and the special characters. Set the content type to **application/json** and encode your json string using `json_encode()`. Also, you don't need the doctypes.

Answer (score 0):

use jquery's parseJSON
e.g.

```
success: function(data) {
    data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
 $('#result').html('#Id=' + data.Id);
}
```

Comment: That will cause more errors since his options have `dataType: 'json'` in it. `data` is already parsed (or failed to, in which case parseJSON will fail again).