# Why am I getting a JSON parsing error from a jQuery Ajax operation?

Tags: json, jquery

I am using jQuery Ajax to return a JSON object (with `dataType: 'json'`) from a PHP file. Here is the returned JSON string that the PHP file echoes out.

```
{'works': true,'text':'<div class=\'animal\'>Elephant</div><br />'}
```

The Chrome web developer console notes `Error:parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected token '`. I do not see, however, where an unexpected single quote could be.

Comment: Thanks, this apparently works: `{"valid": true,"text":"<p class=\"singleComment\">asdfdafdaf</p><hr />"}`. I am kind of confounded though as to why `\'` fails...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Your JSON is invalid](http://json.org/)

Use double quotes. Double quotes!

Comment: Thanks, is this what you mean? `{"valid": true,"text":"<p class=\'singleComment\'>asdfdafdaf</p><hr />"}` Apparently, the parser still oddly complains.

Comment: Now that you're using double quotes, you don't need to escape the single quotes.  JSON only allows, per the string flowchart:
\"
\\
\/
\b
\f
\n
\r
\t
\uXXXX  <= where X is a hexadecimal digit.

Comment: Oh thanks. What if though I actually had a JSON string with a `\'` in it? Like I actually wanted those two characters in my string?

Comment: or better yet, just create the object in a modern browser and call `JSON.stringify(...)` on it.

Comment: JSON.stringify({'works': true,'text':'<div class=\'animal\'>Elephant</div><br />'})  =>
`{"works":true,"text":"<div class='animal'>Elephant</div><br />"}`

Comment: I did that as an example of how to test for yourself if something is properly encoded as as JSON string, not as something you're supposed to do on the server end or anything. I generated the above in Chrome's Console.

Comment: Double quotes doesn't work.  Try this: s='{"key1" : "\"broken\""}'; $.parseJSON(s)

Comment: @shanusmagnus: the syntax of JSON requires double quotes for representing string values (which are also used for keys). To handle double quotes within strings, *you have to properly escape the quotes*. You didn't do that. The string assigned to `s` in your example does not contain the actual escape characters that are necessary. Compare `'{"key1":"\"broken\""}'.indexOf("\\")` with `JSON.stringify({"key1":"\"broken\""}).indexOf("\\")`.  I think you might be letting Chrome console confuse you; it does not unescape strings for console display. A value copied from there may not be code-proper.

Comment: I could have worded that better. Say your value is `Say "Moo!"`.  A encoding of that string into javascript might be `"Say \"Moo!\""`  A encoding of *that* string into javascript (which you'd need to do if you want to use a JSON string directly encoded inline with other lines of javascript)  might be `"\"Say \\\"Moo!\\\"\""`  It's confusing because to use a JSON representation inline with code you have to encode *that JSON representation* as a string. See also `JSON.parse("\"Say \\\"Moo!\\\"\"")`.

Comment: Thanks for this -- apparently parseJSON is actually more liberal than it's supposed to be, and it mostly worked for me.  Thanks to your comment I now understand a weird edge case.

Answer (score 1):

This question is similar of your problem. The echo is correct. See extra content return to client [Creating JSON data using PHP and parsing it using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325695/creating-json-data-using-php-and-parsing-it-using-jquery)