# Using 'loading' curl data after load application

Tags: php, jquery, json, codeigniter, curl

I'm using codeigniter and I have some cURL script in my controller, which will get some big json data and loading of it take about 15-20 seconds.

My view is loading so long like the curl time (15-20s).

How to first load my view with some "loading icon", and after script will download all json data replace "loading icon" with my data?

My code:

**View**:

```
        <?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
            <div class="item-slot">
                <img src="http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/economy/image/<?= $item['icon_url'] ?>">
                <p><?= $item['name'] ?></p>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Controller (open_inventory function)**:

```
public function open_inventory($steam_id, $appid = 730, $contextid = 2)
{
    $data = array("steamid" => $steam_id, "appid" => $appid);                                                                    
    $data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   

    $ch = curl_init('http://localhost:3000/inventory');                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
    );
    $json = json_decode(curl_exec($ch),true);

    if($json['data'])
    {
        return $json['data'];
    }
    return false;
}
```

`$items` in View is `$json['data']` from Controller.

Regards.

Comment: You need to look into using `ajax` calls in your application to retrieve async data from the server.

Comment: @Yani can you tell me what about I need to search into ajax functions to do this? Regards.

Comment: How about http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325695/creating-json-data-using-php-and-parsing-it-using-jquery

Comment: if you have multiple curl calls and in order to speed up things you might want to look into php manual for  `curl_multi_init()` and also here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9311112/2275490

Comment: @Vickel I don't have multiple calls, I have only 1 but it return so big json data and it tooks a long time that's why I want to create something "loading" bar or image.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has the functions ajaxStart and ajaxStop which you could use like this:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
  $("#loading-image").show();
}).ajaxStop(function() {
  $("#loading-image").hide();
});
```

more info [here](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [here](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/)

Comment: can you explain me more how to do this with loading curl json data with php?

Comment: call your php function open_inventory() from view, via ajax

Comment: can you tell me how to call function via ajax?